xorg keyboard configuration
Im on Ubuntu 22.04 with i3, trying to configure the keyboard layout (de). What I tried so far without success:
I followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration and created /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "de"
EndSection

This did not work. I had to invoke setxkbmap de explicitly after startup. I also tried loading the correct keymap via setxkbmap de, by adding it to the following files:

.xsession
.profile
.xinitrc
$CONFIG/i3/config

This had no effect at all.
Adding it to /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default didnt work either and caused a login loop.
How to get the correct settings loaded?
This is the output of setxkbmap -print -verbose 10:
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

And after running setxkbmap de:
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+de+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+de+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

